# Is it possible to automate the operation of a remote application?

Tags: remote-access, rdp

We have a process by which users login to a remote Windows computer via RDP, run a data acquisition application (data entry) and then logoff.  The users are not allowed to install any applications on or copy and data to the remote computer.  The remote session is completely captive; nothing is allowed but clicking on application text entry areas and typing data.

Now this process needs to be expanded so that we can acquire the data with a front-end process that writes the data to the local system **and** to the remote computer.  Since we cannot do anything to the remote computer, is there any way to automate the "clicking and typing" to the RDP session?  The plan would be for the new front-end process to handle the data entry, copy the data to local storage and then *drive* a RDP session to the remote application, supplying the same data to that system also.  One entry of data going to 2 systems.